# Why does the loop iterate beyond Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, loops, integer

Can someone explain why this code is an infinite loop on Java 7,8? The loop should stop when `i = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` but it seems to deny the limit. Why does this happen?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 100; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++);
}
```

Comment: When would you expect an `int` to be larger than the maximum possible value for an `int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at

```
 i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

This is always true. If i = Integer.MAX_VALUE+1 then it will overflow, and become negative.

Do this:

```
 System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE+1)
```

Answer (score 9):

- The value [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) changes from `2147483647` to
  `-2147483648` i.e. [Integer.MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE)when it overflows.
- [Integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) occurs when the arithmetic operation tries to create value that is beyond reach of data type value range.
- In java integers have range from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`.
- In for loop when i becomes `2147483647` then i++ operation will try to increment its value by 1 which is not possible because range is only till `2147483647`.
- So instead of having its value as `2147483648` it will go back to starting value i.e. `-2147483648`
- Hence `i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE` always becomes `true`.
- As condition never becomes `false`, loop will continue till infinity.

You can check value overflow by simply writing your code as below.

```
for (int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 100; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

You will see below output.

```
2147483645
2147483646
2147483647
-2147483648
-2147483647
-2147483646
```

Answer (score 3):

Because when `i` reaches being equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then it becomes `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` which becomes negative

Better would be

```
for (long i = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 100; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
```

Answer (score 3):

You expect the loop to run till `i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE` and stop as soon as it becomes `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1`, i.e., `2147483648`. However, **THAT DOES NOT HAPPEN** because whenever you add something to Integer.MAX_VALUE, say **x**, the calculation takes the form:

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE + x - 1;
```

Since `int` cannot store beyond `2147483647` (and of course beyond `-2147483648`), this thing is done to make sure that there's no overflow. So, after `2147483647`, i becomes `-2147483648`, which is obviously less than `+2147483647` and thus, **it is an infinite loop**.

If you want the loop to iterate in that range (i.e., you just wanna use the values), you can make use of a type cast between `long` and `int` like this:

```
for(long i = (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE - 100; i<= (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
    //to use i as an int, type cast from (long) to (int)
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat You're right. I was just being too ethical :P